# Does anyone know how to make Unity remember your opened windows on logout?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 13.10, windows

Does anyone know how to make Unity remember your opened windows on logout?

I know KDE does this, but would like Unity to remember what applications were loaded and to restart them in the appropriate workspaces and window positions.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in unity as of now..... but it may be a feature anytime soon....u can always install third part desktop environments like kde to do so